# Show image in Calender in ios SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, calendar

In my app, I want to imaplement the month wise calender.

It should display the like as per following image.

[image]

**How can i implement the calender like this?**
**Is thare any third party Library or any in-built classes for calender?**

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [muhku calendar-ui](https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui), its not exactly what you want, but can be a good start. may be you can tweak it, and achieve what you need

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it is only for week/grid view. Not for month view.

Comment: @user1896921 you can also try tapku library.